# I need an Excel Macro that will automatically select "Yes" for a pop-up window regarding a name that already exists

Tags: excel, vba

I've built a Macro that will copy all of the sheets in one workbook and paste them into another workbook. So far it works just fine, but while the macro is in the midst of copying and pasting each sheet, excel flashes a pop up window that reads "The name '(insert any name here)' already exists. Click Yes to use that version of the name, or click No to rename the version of '(insert any name here)' you're moving or copying."

It does this for multiple named items that have the same name in the sheets that I'm copying and pasting to the new workbook, so this window pops up a lot (about 30 times!). Is there a Macro that will automatically select "Yes" so I don't have to keep selecting yes over and over again? I've listed the macro for copying and pasting all worksheets into another workbook of mine below for reference.

```
Sub Copy_Sheets()

Dim b1 As Workbook, b2 As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Documents\Test.xlsx"
Set b1 = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Experiment.xlsx"
Set b2 = ActiveWorkbook

For Each sh In b2.Sheets
 sh.Copy After:=b1.Sheets(b1.Sheets.Count)
Next sh


End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before the `sh.Copy` statement, and then make sure to do `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` after that statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

before the copying, and

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

after.

This way you'll turn off the alerts before copying and will turn them on after.

Comment: I'm trying to see if this solution works, but I' now getting a runtime error '1004' stating "That name is already taken. Try a different one."  on the line reading:          sh.Copy After:=b1.Sheets(b1.Sheets.Count). Any idea what it means?